# How to disable button on parent record in lightning:treegrid component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I am newbie to lightning and I am having treegrid lightning component in which I have button column. My requirement is to disable or hide the button on parent record. Below are my code. I am not sure whether we can override this standard behavior.

**Component**

```
 <aura:attribute name= "buttondisable" type= "boolean" default= "true" />
 <lightning:treeGrid aura:id="abc" 
                            columns="{!v.gridColumns}" 
                            data="{!v.gridData}" 
                            keyField="Order"
                            expandedRows="{!v.gridExpandedRows}"
                            onrowaction="{! c.callview }"
                            />
```

**Controller.js**

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
var columns = [
            {
                type: 'text',
                fieldName: 'Order',
                label: 'Order Checked',

            },
            {
                type: 'currency',
                fieldName: 'Total',
                label: 'Total'
            },
            {
                type: 'dropdown',
                fieldName: 'test',
                label: 'test'
            },
           {
                type: 'button',
               fieldName: 'test1',
                label: 'View Detail',
                    typeAttributes: {
                        iconName: '',
                        name: 'validate', 
                        title: 'View Detail',
                        label:'View Detail',
                        alternativeText:'Return',
                        variant: 'brand', 
                        disabled: component.get('v.buttondisable')
                    }
            }

        ];
         component.set('v.gridColumns', columns);
}
```

[image]
I want the button to be enabled only for child records. I have created this attribute `component.get('v.buttondisable')` so that I tried to pass this value as `false` from child record but this is not working.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need use row-based data to make if the button item is disabled or not, this should be done by your row data. before you bind your data in to aura attribute (in below example i used "isbutton") , you should bind extra field in to your data please use below tested code. i used [data from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/octz9.png) since i don't have your data set up

cmp:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
 <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:attribute name="gridColumns" type="List" access="PRIVATE" />
<aura:attribute name="gridData" type="Object" access="PRIVATE" />
<aura:attribute name="gridExpandedRows" type="List" access="PRIVATE" />
<aura:attribute name="currentExpandedRows" type="String" />


<div>
    <p class="slds-m-top_medium slds-m-bottom_medium">
        <lightning:button label="Get Current Expanded Rows" onclick="{! c.getState }"></lightning:button>
        <p>Current expanded rows: {! v.currentExpandedRows }</p>
    </p>

    <lightning:treeGrid
        aura:id="treeGrid"
        columns="{! v.gridColumns }"
        data="{! v.gridData }"
        onrowaction = "{!c.handlerowaction}"
        expandedRows="{! v.gridExpandedRows }"
        keyField="name"
    />
</div>
```

controller.js

```
({
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
     var actions = helper.getRowActions.bind(this, component);        // data
    var nestedData = [
        {
            "name": "123555",
            "accountName": "Rewis Inc",
            "employees": 3100,
            "phone": "837-555-1212",
            "accountOwner": "http://example.com/jane-doe",
            "accountOwnerName": "Jane Doe",
            "billingCity": "Phoeniz, AZ",
             "isbutton":"slds-hide",
        },

        {
            "name": "123556",
            "accountName": "Acme Corporation",
            "employees": 10000,
            "phone": "837-555-1212",
            "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
            "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
            "billingCity": "San Francisco, CA",
             "isbutton":"slds-hide",
            "_children": [
                {
                    "name": "123556-A",
                    "accountName": "Acme Corporation (Bay Area)",
                    "employees": 3000,
                    "phone": "837-555-1212",
                    "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                    "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                    "billingCity": "New York, NY",
                     "isbutton":"slds-show"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "123557",
            "accountName": "Rhode Enterprises",
            "employees": 6000,
            "phone": "837-555-1212",
            "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
            "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
            "billingCity": "New York, NY",
            "isbutton":'slds-hide',
            "_children": [
                {
                    "name": "123557-A",
                    "accountName": "Rhode Enterprises (UCA)",
                    "employees": 2540,
                    "phone": "837-555-1212",
                    "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                    "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                    "billingCity": "New York, NY",
                    "isbutton":'slds-show'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "123558",
            "accountName": "Tech Labs",
            "employees": 1856,
            "phone": "837-555-1212",
            "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
            "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
            "billingCity": "New York, NY",
             "isbutton":'slds-hide',
            "_children": [
                {
                    "name": "123558-A",
                    "accountName": "Opportunity Resources Inc",
                    "employees": 1934,
                    "phone": "837-555-1212",
                    "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                    "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                    "billingCity": "Los Angeles, CA",
                     "isbutton":'slds-show'
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

    component.set('v.gridData', nestedData);
     var expandedRows = ["123556", "123557","123558"];

    component.set('v.gridExpandedRows', expandedRows);
    component.set('v.gridColumns', [
        {
            type: 'text',
            fieldName: 'accountName',
            label: 'Account Name',
            initialWidth: 300
        },
        {
            type: 'number',
            fieldName: 'employees',
            label: 'Employees'
        },
        {
            type: 'phone',
            fieldName: 'phone',
            label: 'Phone Number'
        },
        {
            type: 'url',
            fieldName: 'accountOwner',
            label: 'Account Owner',
            typeAttributes: {
                label: { fieldName: 'accountOwnerName' }
            }
        },
        {
            type: 'text',
            fieldName: 'billingCity',
            label: 'Billing City'
        },
        {
            type: 'button',
           fieldName: 'test1',
            label: 'View Detail',
                typeAttributes: {
                    iconName: '',
                    name: 'validate', 
                    title: 'View Detail',
                    label:'View Detail',
                    alternativeText:'Return',
                    variant: 'brand', 
                    class: {fieldName: 'isbutton'}
                }
        }

    ]);
},
})
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome !!!!. It works great. Is there nay similar way where i Can completely remove the button on parent.

Comment: I am also looking to remove the checkbox in parent is that do able?

Comment: you can hide and show instead disabled & Enabled by using "class" Attribute just like add " class: {fieldName: 'isbutton'}" instead of  "disabled: {fieldName: 'isbutton'}" but your data should be set up  "slds-hide / slds-show" instead of true /false

Comment: I believe there is no `class:` attribute for button. Correct me If I am wrong, It showing error when I try to put `class` attribute

Comment: button had class attribute, it works for me, i updated  answer with latest code and result image, please have a look

Comment: Yes I missed case-sensitive issue now i corrected my code and its working like gem. You are awesome. Lightning is more interesting.